# ModelForm instance doesn't store primary key

Tags: python, django

Upon trying to save a Model instance as a result of saving a ModelForm, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: "<Question: NameError: 'x' is not defined>" needs to have 
a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

The question instance is being created to an extent, yet the primary key is not being generated. What needs to be fixed in order for the primary key to be attached so it can be stored in the database?

```
class PostQuestionPage(QuestionPage):

    template_name="questions/create_question.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['question_form'] = QuestionForm(self.request.POST or None)
        con
        return context


    def get(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['question_form']
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.user_account = request.user.account
            question.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse("questions:question", kwargs={'id': question.id})
            )
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    dated = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserAccount',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="questions"
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='questions')

    objects = models.Manager()
    dateranges = DateRangeQuerySet.as_manager()
    status = QuestionStatusQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dated']
        default_manager_name = "objects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class TestPostQuestionPageAdded(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a User has succesfully added a question'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = User.objects.create_user("Me")
        cls.account = UserAccount.objects.create(user=cls.user)
        tag1 = Tag.objects.create(name="tag1")
        tag2 = Tag.objects.create(name="tag2")
        cls.data = mock_questions_submitted[1]
        cls.data.update(
            {'tags': [tag1, tag2]}
        )

    def test_user_submitted_question_added(self):
        total_questions = Question.objects.count()
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("questions:create"),
            data=self.data,
        )
        question = Question.objects.all().get()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(Question.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(question.user_account, self.account)
```

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x0000024F9A49D788>, 'id': None, 
'title': 'What is a primary key?', 
'body': "<p>Upon studying database relationships, a relation happens to be set of records\nof the same type that is stored in the database. Yet, I'm not understanding\nwhat purpose the primary key serves? How does a record benefit from having\na primary key?</p>", 
'dated': datetime.date(2021, 4, 26), 
'likes': 0, 'user_account_id': 1}

(Pdb) question.tags
*** ValueError: "<Question: What is a primary key?>" 
needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: Add the `QuestionForm` also